# Создание jabber веб-клиента

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-служба

Всем привет! Народ подскажите, пожалуйста, у кого какие мысли есть на тему создания собственного jabber веб-клиента. Есть необходимость создать jabber веб-клиент, поиски в гугле сводятся к одним и тем же веб-клиентам с открытым исходным кодом (как правило все они кривые), а также были почти инструкции по создания собственного веб-клиента, но это все не то, что нужно. Интересно ваше мнение и опыт, может кто-нить уже сталкивался с такой проблемой, может кто-нить знает полезные ресурсы, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Год назад допиливал веб чат поддержки. Компоненты:

- интерфейс на jQueryUI
- библиотека XMPP [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/)
- сервер [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/) с модулем [http_bind](http://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd_http_bind)

В исходниках Strophe.js есть [примеры](https://github.com/metajack/strophejs/tree/master/examples)

Comment: Воспользовался готовым веб-клиентом [Jappix][1], пока вроде полет нормальный, единственное не могу понять, почему у меня группы в списке контактов не все сворачиваются, был момент, админы переименовали название всех групп на латиницу, после этого некоторые группы начали сворачиваться и разворачиваться нормально, а у некоторых замечена странность, когда нажимаю по группе свернуть/развернуть то сворачивается/разворачивается другая группа.


  [1]: http://jappix.org/

Answer (score 0):

[XMPP](https://www.google.ru/#hl=ru&gs_nf=1&tok=oQg6lqg56-dVfsYf7PVbrw&cp=3&gs_id=6b&xhr=t&q=xmpp&pf=p&newwindow=1&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=xmp&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=1e73a14cfad73782&biw=1600&bih=768) а дальше по накатанной находите готовые библиотеки под выбранный язык и пилите пилите пилите=)